# How to change font color of specific date in jQuery calendar?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the font color of a particular date of a calendar using jQuery in WordPress.

```
var d= new date("February 21, 2017");
d.css('color','black');
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each td in your table, check its contents, and apply the css as needed.

```
$('#your-table-id-here').find('td').each (function() {
      if(this.text() === "February 21, 2017"){
         this.css('color','black');
    }
});
```